# Android - Fading Layout Border

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I am working on an android app and I have a scrollview, and in that, I have a linear layout in the main activity. I want to have the top and bottom borders of the linear layout to be "faded
" so as the user scrolls down the child views in the layout will "fade out" as the go down.

[Here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_C5a2qH8Y_jk/TDYb7lA_lnI/AAAAAAAAAgk/AOy7va5fhQg/s1600/AndroidList_07.png) is an example of what I am trying to achieve in my linearlayout or scrollview (the "fading bottom border".

Thanks for you help!
Subby

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your layout, you can have a view above the listView, and set Gradient Color for the view, and also make it semitransparent, then you can have the effect you want.

Comment: Hi, I actually want to make it clear that I have a scrollview, and a nested linear layout. I want to achieve the same thing from the list view expect I do not have any list view in my activity. I want the top and bottom of my linear layout/scrollview to have that "fade"effect. Thanks!

Comment: My solution also does not care it a listview or a scrollview.

Comment: I know, but is there another way, like a property of a scroll view or any layout that can do this, as it is frequently used by many apps I use?

Comment: I don't think scroll view or layout has this kind of property.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the following attributes in the ScrollView.

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
```

If you want it on devices before API14, you need to use the following:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
```

NOTE: This is actually discouraged as it is seen to have a negative performance impact on devices.